# Ubuntu Core: Is it possible to use an external encrypted file system?

Tags: boot, mount, encryption, ubuntu-core

I am playing with a Raspberry Pi 3 and Ubuntu Core. One of the requirements I have for taking it into a more serious use, is the capacity to manage encrypted drives, like mounting them during the boot sequence.

I could not find `cryptsetup` on the Snap Store. Is it possible to mount encrypted drives on Ubuntu Core during boot in some other way?

Edit: I'm not looking for a full encryption of the Ubuntu Core filesystem, my purpose is to mount an existing encrypted drive as part of the Ubuntu Core filesystem.

Edit2: As mentioned before, I'm not looking for a fully encrypted Ubuntu Core system. I want to mount externally encrypted drives. I'm doing exactly that with Rasbpian, and I want to know if it is possible with Ubuntu Core